# Java ISBN checksum generator -- infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, integer, infinite-loop

I need to build this ISBN checksum generator (for both ISBN-10 and ISBN-13) for my CS class using strings, chars, and a bunch of nested loops and conditional statements. Somewhere in this mess, I think something is triggering an infinite loop because when I am prompted for an input, I give the input and press enter and it just goes to a new line and expects me to enter a bunch more data I guess when instead it should be prompting me again to enter another one after each successful entry and otherwise tell me it's incorrect and then still again ask for another input. And when I type in quit it doesn't end the program and display the checksum results like it's supposed to, instead it exhibits the same behavior as other inputs do. If I type in quit the first time without giving the program any numbers it does end the program properly but of course, the values of the output variables are null.

My code thus far:

```
/******************************************************************************
 * Program Name:          Lab05A - ISBN
 * Program Description:   Calculate ISBN-10 AND ISBN-13
 * Program Author:        xxxxxxxxx
 * Date Created:          10/10/2018
 * Change#        Change Date      Programmer Name        Description
 * -------        ------------     -------------------    ---------------------
******************************************************************************/
package lab05a;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab05A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Input for s
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Create new scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: "); // our ever-lasting prompt
        String s = input.next(); // declare string variable "s" and set it equal to next input from user.
        String output10 = null; // Declaring string output10
        String output13 = null; // Declaring string output13
        // main while loop
        while (!"QUIT".equals(s)) { //this will run as long as the program does not receive an input of "QUIT", not case sensitive.
            char checkDigit;
            char checkSum = '0';
            if (s.length() == 9) { //if the length of the inputted string is 9 characters...
                int sum = 0; // initialize sum variable
                for (int i=0; i <= s.length();) {
                    sum = sum + ((s.charAt(i) - '0') * (i + 1));
                }
                if (sum % 11 == 10) {
                    checkDigit = 'X';
                }
                else {
                    checkDigit = (char) ('0' + (sum % 11));
                }
                output10 = output10 + "\n" + s + checkDigit;
                System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                s = input.next();
            }
            else if  (s.length() == 12) {
               int sum = 0;
                for (int i=0; i <= s.length();) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        sum = sum + (s.charAt(i) - '0');
                    }
                    else {
                        sum = sum + (s.charAt(i) - '0') * 3;
                    }
                    checkSum = (char) (10 - sum % 10);
                    if (checkSum == 10) {
                        checkSum = 0;
                    }
                    output13 = "\n" + output13 + checkSum;
                    System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                    s = input.next();
                }
            }
            else if (!s.toUpperCase().equals("QUIT")) {
                System.out.println(s + " is invalid input.");
                System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                s = input.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The 10 digit ISBNs are \n" + output10);
        System.out.println("The 13 digit ISBNs are \n" + output13);
    }
}
```

[Instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmbz23hkvht2uw9/Lab05A%20Assignment.pdf?dl=0)

[Flowchart as a separate image since it's kinda small in the instructions doc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ek2a5pol6atkfc/lab05a%20flowchart.png?dl=0)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing the incrementor in this `for` loop

```
for (int i=0; i <= s.length();) {
```

change to

```
for (int i=0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
```

I am sure that you do not want `<=`, maybe just `<`

so

```
for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
```

**BTW** this is easy to solve if you debug your code - an essential skill --

**edit**

If you have the below code (and s.length == 12)

```
for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
    s = input.next();
}
```

Then it will execute 12 times. Fix your loop

Comment: That solved that part of the problem, but there is still some issues with getting "QUIT" which when inputted should end the program and print the results of the computations It only works when it's in all uppercase, but it is supposed to be case insensitive.

Comment: `while (!"QUIT".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {`

Comment: Oddly enough that doesn't seem to change the behavior of the program. And what's strange is if I test both the 9 digit and 12 digit numbers, then I have to type in QUIT in all caps around 4 to 5 times before it seems to register my input. We literally just learned to debug in Netbeans today and I'm still trying to get the grasp of it. I probably need to find a good tutorial of it.

Comment: Yes, I would personally move the processing code to a seperate method, it will make the handling of input a lot cleaner `loop -> input -> isQuit (break) -> process`

Comment: Unfortunately, methods is the next chapter and our professor has a strict rule where we can't use the future chapter's information and skills to solve the current chapter's problems. So if this was a personal project I would try and implement your suggestion but I don't wanna get points deducted for trying that.
I did some debugging and when I type in QUIT, this is what I get: https://gyazo.com/f10bcd0330c28f8ec4de3a6823c50c1d
I think it's an issue related to the conversion of chars and strings and that stuff, but I'm not entirely sure exactly where in my code.

Comment: The only code I can see is the `if` statement, did you change the `while` parts as I commented?  Anyway, if this question answered your original question please consider to upvote and/or accept

Comment: I did change the while statements to what you suggested. And I don't think my original question is completely solved since I am getting fewer loop issues than before but still there are critical things I need help debugging. If you haven't already please do see if there are any stupid mistakes I might have overlooked when comparing with the flowchart that I provided. I will post my updated code so far below.

Comment: I copied your below posted code and there is **no** infinite loop.  When I type `quit` it quits

Comment: It doesn't quit in this instance of a sample run:
`run:
Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: 
123456789012
Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: 
quit
Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: 
quit
Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: 
quit
Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: 
quit
The 10 digit ISBNs are 

The 13 digit ISBNs are 




 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)`

Comment: If I immediately type quit or if I type in one 9 digit number and quit, then it works without issues. So I still need to figure out what is wrong with the section of my code involving the 12-digit numbers.

Comment: The code beginning with `output13 = "\n" + output13 + s + checkSum;` is within your `for` loop, so of course it will be executed `12` times

Comment: I couldn't get that to work and debugging it says that my output13 variable is equal to some random Unicode characters like \u0003.  BTWputting the code for output13 outside of the for loop seems to contradict the flowchart provided by my instructor unless I am interpreting the flowchart incorrectly.

Comment: Where ya gone to Ryan?

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED CODE since I implemented some of the suggestions here:

```
package lab05a;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab05A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Input for s
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Create new scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: "); // our ever-lasting prompt
        String s = input.next(); // declare string variable "s" and set it equal to next input from user.
        String output10 = ""; // Declaring string output10
        String output13 = ""; // Declaring string output13
        // main while loop
        while (!"QUIT".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) { //this will run as long as the program does not receive an input of "QUIT", not case sensitive.
            char checkDigit;
            char checkSum = '0';
            if (s.length() == 9) { //if the length of the inputted string is 9 characters...
                int sum = 0; // initialize sum variable
                for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    sum = sum + ((s.charAt(i) - '0') * (i + 1));
                }
                if (sum % 11 == 10) {
                    checkDigit = 'X';
                }
                else {
                    checkDigit = (char) ('0' + (sum % 11));
                }
                output10 = output10 + "\n" + s + checkDigit;
                System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                s = input.next();
            }
            else if  (s.length() == 12) {
               int sum = 0;
                for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        sum = sum + (s.charAt(i) - '0');
                    }
                    else {
                        sum = sum + (s.charAt(i) - '0') * 3;
                    }
                    checkSum = (char) (10 - sum % 10);
                    if (checkSum == 10) {
                        checkSum = 0;
                    }
                    output13 = "\n" + output13 + s + checkSum;
                    System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                    s = input.next();
                }
            }
            else if (!"QUIT".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                System.out.println(s + " is invalid input.");
                System.out.println("Enter the first 9 or 12 digits of an ISBN number. Enter QUIT to exit: ");
                s = input.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The 10 digit ISBNs are \n" + output10);
        System.out.println("The 13 digit ISBNs are \n" + output13);
    }
}
```